# Get ids on windows

Tags: c#

I have an error that I cannot solve, not even searching the internet.
My code:

```
public static void GetClasses(ref List<ListViewItem> items)
    {
        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\ROOT\\CIMV2", SystemInformation.ComputerName.ToUpperInvariant()));
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            EnablePrivileges = true,
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default,
            Username = null,
            SecurePassword = null
        };
        ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
        managementScope.Connect();
        ObjectGetOptions options2 = new ObjectGetOptions();
        new ManagementScope(new ManagementObject(managementScope, path, options2).Path, options);
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM meta_class WHERE __Class LIKE \"%%%\" AND NOT __Class LIKE \"[_][_]%\" AND NOT __Class LIKE \"Win32_Perf%\" AND NOT __Class LIKE \"MSFT[_]%\"");
        EnumerationOptions options3 = new EnumerationOptions
        {
            EnumerateDeep = true,
            UseAmendedQualifiers = true
        };
        ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, query, options3);
        new List<WMIClass>();
        foreach (ManagementClass managementClass in from ManagementClass currentClass in managementObjectSearcher.Get()
                                                    orderby currentClass.ClassPath.ClassName
                                                    select currentClass)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            // using (ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator enumerator2 = disks.GetEnumerator())
            using (PropertyDataCollection.PropertyDataEnumerator enumerator2 = ManagementClass.Properties.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (enumerator2.Current.Type == CimType.String)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                WMIClass wmiclass = new WMIClass(managementClass);
                ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem
                {
                    Name = wmiclass.DisplayName,
                    Text = wmiclass.DisplayName,
                    ToolTipText = wmiclass.Description,
                    Tag = wmiclass
                };
                listViewItem.SubItems.Add(wmiclass.Description);
                items.Add(listViewItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Error line:

```
using (PropertyDataCollection.PropertyDataEnumerator enumerator2 = ManagementClass.Properties.GetEnumerator())
// using (ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator enumerator2 = disks.GetEnumerator())
```

I don't know what the mistake is. If you can help me please I don't understand the language very well.
I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the error? What are you trying to do? Can you put together a [mcve] to allow others to try and compile this?

Comment: please post the error.  Preferably the entire stack trace.

Comment: What is error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
using (PropertyDataCollection.PropertyDataEnumerator enumerator2 = ManagementClass.Properties.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
    {
        if (enumerator2.Current.Type == CimType.String)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
PropertyDataCollection.PropertyDataEnumerator enumerator2 = managementClass.Properties.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
{
    if (enumerator2.Current.Type == CimType.String)
    {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

First, "using" must be removed because GetEnumerator() does not return a disposable object and second, use "managementClass.Properties.GetEnumerator()" instead of "ManagementClass.Properties.GetEnumerator()".

Comment: Could you help me to collect the id of the pc ?. Take the code of a program but it does not get me all the id's and in the program where it guides me yes.